# An integer sequence related to Pascal’s triangle

Tags: binomial-coefficients, integer-sequences

We need someone expert in binomial coefficients (subject 11B65) to recognize the integer sequence generated by an iterative formula we have encountered while working on a project about Pascal’s triangle.

Given a prime $p>2$ and an integer $1 \leq k \leq \frac{p-5}{2}$, let us define the following recursion

$$ n_k = \frac{1 + (–1)^{k+2} \binom{p-1}{k+1}}{p} + (–1)^{k+1} \binom{p-3}{k} +(–1)^k n_1 \binom{p-5}{k-1} + (–1)^{k-1} n_2 \binom{p-7}{k-2} + \cdots + n_{k-1} \binom{k+1}{1}$$

whose elements are:

$$ n_1 = \frac{1-\binom{p-1}{2}}{p} + \binom{p-3}{1}$$

$$ n_2 = \frac{1+\binom{p-1}{3}}{p} - \binom{p-3}{2} + n_1 \binom{p-5}{1}$$

$$ n_3 = \frac{1-\binom{p-1}{4}}{p} + \binom{p-3}{3} - n_1 \binom{p-5}{2} + n_2 \binom{p-7}{1}$$

$$ \dots $$

**Is it related to any known sequences?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try to use generating functions?

Comment: Dear @AlexeyUstinov, thank you for your kind attention. We tried several ways and we explored the OEIS without any success. The only hint we received, from a brilliant researcher, was that there could be a connection with Cauchy polynomials. Anyway, it was a too vague suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is related to known sequences.

Polynomials $(k+1)!n_k(p)$, where $p$ is treated as a variable, have coefficients triangle
$$
1,\\
-3,1,\\
20,-9,1,\\
-210,107,-18,1,\\
...................
$$
given by the OEIS sequence [A038455](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C-3%2C1%2C20%2C-9%2C1&language=english&go=Search).