# A polynomial identity for $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

I asked this question on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4860350/a-conjecture-on-representing-sum-limits-k-0-m-1kam-kbk-as-sum-of-p).

---

I was solving this problem:

> Show that if $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $p$ is an odd prime, then $\displaystyle \gcd\left(a+b, \frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}\right)=1$ or $p$.

This is an elementary problem in number theory, but I wonder how to represent $\frac{a^p+b^p}{a+b}$ in terms of powers of $a+b$.

$$\sum_{k=0} ^2 (-1)^k a^{2-k}b^k = (a+b)^2 -3ab$$
$$\sum_{k=0} ^4 (-1)^k a^{4-k}b^k = (a+b)^4 -5(ab)(a+b)^2 +5(ab)^2$$
$$\sum_{k=0} ^6 (-1)^k a^{6-k}b^k = (a+b)^6 -7(ab)(a+b)^4 +7 \cdot 2(ab)^2(a+b)^2 -7(ab)^3$$

I noticed that  for $m=p-1$ ($p$ is an odd prime number)
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k=(a+b)^m +(m+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac m 2} g_m(k)(-(ab))^k  (a+b)^{m-2k}\right)$, Where $g_m(k): \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (I was not able to find a way to determine  of $g_m(k)$ ).

So my question is: How to prove that for any $m=p-1$ ($p$ is an odd prime number) $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k=(a+b)^m +(m+1)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac m 2} g_m(k)(-(ab))^k  (a+b)^{m-2k}\right)$ and how to find $g_m(k)$.

Comment: This looks a lot like the identity in [B. Sury, *A parent of Binet’s formula?*, 2004](https://www.isibang.ac.in/~sury/binetpf.pdf). But it's not quite the same, since the powers of $-1$ don't match (an identity like yours can exist when $m$ is even), but the $m+1$ factor you have should be due to the mod-$p$ behavior of binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we introduce the elementary symmetric polynomials $e_1 = a+b$, $e_2 = ab$ and the power sums $p_q = a^q + b^q$, then from the [Newton identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) we have
$$ p_1 = e_1; p_2 = e_1 p_1 - e_2$$
and
$$ p_q = e_1 p_{q-1} - e_2 p_{q-2}$$
for $q>2$, which by induction gives a representation
$$ p_q = e_1^q + \sum_{1 \leq j \leq q/2} c_{q,j} e_1^{q-2j} e_2^j$$
for some integer coefficients $c_{q,j}$.  In particular for $q$ odd, we have
$$ \frac{p_q}{p_1} = e_1^{q-1} + \sum_{1 \leq j \leq q/2} c_{q,j} e_1^{q-2j-1} e_2^j. \quad (*)$$
To answer your question, one just needs to demonstrate that each of the integers $c_{q,j}$ is divisible by $q$ when $q$ is an odd prime.  One way to do this is to use the quadratic formula
$$ a,b = \frac{e_1 \pm \sqrt{e_1^2 - 4e_2}}{2}$$
which when inserted in to the binomial formula gives
$$ \frac{p_q}{p_1} = \sum_{0 \leq j \leq q/2} 2^{1-q} \binom{q}{2j} e_1^{q-2j-1} (e_1^2-4e_2)^j$$
and then noting that all of the binomial coefficients $\binom{q}{2j}$ except for the $j=0$ one will be divisible by $q$, hence the coefficients $c_{q,j}$ are equal to a multiple of $q$ divided by $2^{1-q}$, and hence divisible by $q$ since $q$ is odd. Note that this approach also gives an explicit formula for your coefficients $g_m(k)$, namely
$$ g_m(k) = \frac{1}{2^{m-2k} (m+1)} \sum_{k \leq j \leq m/2} \binom{m+1}{2j} \binom{j}{k}.$$
[Sidenote: it was an [easy matter](https://chat.openai.com/share/1528b175-2643-4dae-ae41-f56d72f6e579) to check this formula against the examples you listed with ChatGPT.]

Another approach is to observe from Fermat's little theorem that $\frac{p_q}{p_1} - e_1^{q-1}$ vanishes mod $q$ for any integer $a,b$ (treating the case $a+b=0 \hbox{ mod } q$ separately), hence (on setting $x = e_1^2, y = e_2$) the polynomial $\sum_{1 \leq j \leq q/2} c_{q,j} x^{\frac{q-1}{2}-j} y^j$ vanishes mod $q$ whenever $x$ and $x-4y$ are both quadratic residues mod $q$.  The [Schwartz-Zippel lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma) then forces the coefficients to vanish mod $q$ as well, since the number $\frac{q+1}{2}$ of quadratic residues exceeds the degree $\frac{q-1}{2}$ of this polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

The homogeneous integral polynomial
$$P_m(a,b):=\sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^ka^{m-k}b^k\in\mathbb{Z}[a,b]$$
satisfies (upon writing $j=m-k$)
$$P_m(b,a)=\sum_{k=0} ^m (-1)^kb^{m-k}a^k=\sum_{j=0} ^m (-1)^{m-j}b^ja^{m-j}=(-1)^mP_m(a,b).$$
Assume that $m$ is even. Then $P_m(a,b)$ is symmetric by the above, hence by the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, it is an integral polynomial of the elementary symmetric polynomials $a+b$ and $ab$. That is,
$$P_m(a,b)=\sum_{k=0}^{m/2}h_m(k)(ab)^k(a+b)^{m-2k}$$
for some $h_m(k)\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Multiplying both sides by $a+b$ and detaching the term corresponding to $k=0$, we get
$$a^{m+1}+b^{m+1}=(a+b)^{m+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{m/2}h_m(k)(ab)^k(a+b)^{m+1-2k}.$$
Assume now that $m+1=p$ is a prime. Then the left-hand side and the first term on the right-hand side are equal as polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$, hence the coefficients $h_m(k)$ for $1\leq k\leq m/2$ are divisible $p$ (again by the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials). So in this case we have
$$P_m(a,b)=(a+b)^m+(m+1)\sum_{k=0}^{m/2}g_m(k)(ab)^k(a+b)^{m-2k}$$
for some $g_m(k)\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are looking for a binomial arrangement like this:

$$ a^p+b^p = (a+b)^p - pab(a+b)((a+b)^{p-3} - ab(n_1(a+b)^{p-5} – ab(n_2(a+b)^{p-7} + \cdots -ab(n_{\frac{p-5}{2}} (a+b)^2-ab) \cdots)))$$

where $n_1$, $n_2$, $ \dots$, $n_{\frac{p-5}{2}}$ are defined [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/463899/an-integer-sequence-related-to-pascal-s-triangle).